# Задача с перемещением по квадрату 10х10 между точками

Tags: python, алгоритм

Дан список с 4-мя значениями в виде `[53, 38, 35, 56]` (координаты на квадрате, которые эквивалентны (5, 3) (3, 8), (3, 5) и (5, 6) соответственно). Если первая цифра (вертикаль `x`) равна `0`, то пишется только координата `y`, то есть если мы имеем (0, 5) - она будет записываться в виде: `5`. Необходимо написать функцию, которая принимает этот список, в котором первый элемент - это `точка старта`, второй, третий и четвертый - это пункты, которые мнимый объект должен пересечь (в порядке размещения элементов). Функция должна вернуть список из элементов, которые будут отображать пошаговое перемещение.

**Технические подробности**:

1. Путь должен проходить через каждый пункт ​​один раз и в порядке возрастания.
2. Путь не должен пересекаться / накладываться друг на друга.
3. Расстояние, преодолеваемое путем, должно быть минимально необходимым для выполнения задачи.
4. Полный набор 30 тестов : фиксированные тесты, 100: случайные тесты
5. Входные данные всегда будут действительны, и каждый тест будет иметь ноль или более возможных решений.

**Иллюстрированный пример**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Входной список на данном примере: [0, 65, 93, 36].

Выходной список для `рисунка B`: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 64, 63, 73, 83, 93, 94, 95, 96, 86, 76, 66, 56, 46, 36].

Набросал код, в итоге из 30 тестов проходит только 10-15. И я понимаю из-за чего. Дело в том, что такой простой логики здесь недостаточно, необходимо как-то решить проблему с пересечениями, например если взять такой список: `[53, 38, 35, 56]`, путь начинает накладываться сам на себя, и я до сих пор не могу решить эту проблему.

**Непосредственно мой код:**

```
def four_pass(stations):
    x = stations[0]
    points = [x]

    for y in range(1, 4):
        while x != stations[y]:
            if 0 > x > 9:
                break
            if x % 10 < stations[y] % 10 and x + 1 not in points:
                if x + 1 not in stations[y+1:]:
                    x += 1
                    points.append(x)
                else:
                    if x - 10 not in stations[y+1:]:
                        x -= 10
                        points.append(x)
                    else:
                        x += 10
                        points.append(x)
            elif x % 10 > stations[y] % 10 and x - 1 not in points:
                if x - 1 not in stations[y + 1:]:
                    x -= 1
                    points.append(x)
                else:
                    if x - 10 not in stations[y + 1:]:
                        x -= 10
                        points.append(x)
                    else:
                        x += 10
                        points.append(x)
            elif x // 10 < stations[y] // 10 and x + 10 not in points:
                if x + 10 not in stations[y + 1:]:
                    x += 10
                    points.append(x)
                else:
                    if x - 1 not in stations[y + 1:]:
                        x -= 1
                        points.append(x)
                    else:
                        x += 1
                        points.append(x)
            elif x // 10 > stations[y] // 10 and x - 10 not in points:
                if x - 10 not in stations[y + 1:]:
                    x -= 10
                    points.append(x)
                else:
                    if x - 1 not in stations[y + 1:]:
                        x -= 1
                        points.append(x)
                    else:
                        x += 1
                        points.append(x)
            else:
                break

    print(points)


four_pass([37,61,92,36])
```

Comment: Мне кажется тут только перебирать все возможные пути, отбирать из них прошедшие через все точки и потом брать кратчайший. По типу как первые шахматные программы перебирали варианты на сколько-то ходов вперёд. А тут вообще все ходы придётся перебрать, видимо

Comment: Наверняка это будет затратно по времени исполнения...

Comment: Да уж. Ну или пробовать только кратчайшие варианты пути между точками перебирать. Не знаю какие там вообще есть примеры. Надо пробовать. В принципе, питон десятки тысяч вычислений может в секунду делать, если простые какие-то действия.

Comment: @CrazyElf, те клетки, на которых цифры, тоже считаются. То есть с нуля нумерование

Comment: А, да, дошло ))

Comment: @CrazyElf  =))))

Comment: Нужно написать алгоритм, который будет всегда двигаться "по часовой стрелке".  То есть учитывая min(y[current:]) делать траекторию "левее" этого значения. Надеюсь, идея понятна?

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, идея понятна, но только на 80%. Можете показать на иллюстрации, если не затруднит?